# Fetch values from different tables with same ID

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with some the sql querys when calling from different tables.

Im trying to get some results from 2 tables.
In this case, i would like to get the values from user.id=1 and the values of the user that user.id=1 is following.

but it always ending up giving me only either all the users that have the same follow_id ore only result from user.id = 1.

I was thinking of something like this, but this query gives empty results.

```
SELECT 
user.email, user.username, tweets.message, tweets.date, userdetails.profile_img,           userdetails.firstname, userdetails.lastname, following.id, following.user_id, following.follow_id
FROM user
JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
JOIN tweets ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
JOIN following ON following.follow_id
WHERE user.id = following.follow_id AND user.id = 1
```

Tables.
    Following
    id | user_id | follow_id

```
Tweets
user_id|id|date|message

user
id|email|password|username

userdetails
id|firstname|lastname|profile_img|user_id|about
```

Comment: Your question says "the values of users that have the same `follow_id`".  The same `follow_id` as what?  Can you give an example of data and the results you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The same follow_id as user.id .

Its like a twitter application im trying to create for studing purpose.
So if user 2 whats to follow user 1. I add user 1 to follow_id

Comment: A little unclear to what you realy want here, is it info about the user with ID 1 and also info about all the users following the user with ID = 1?

Comment: @ChristerBacklundHøllesli Im supposed to get the values of user.id=1 and the values of the user user.id 1 is following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
user.email, user.username, tweets.message, tweets.date, userdetails.profile_img,userdetails.firstname, userdetails.lastname, '' as id, '' as user_id, '' as follow_id
FROM user
JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
JOIN tweets ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
WHERE user.id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
user.email, user.username, tweets.message, tweets.date, userdetails.profile_img,userdetails.firstname, userdetails.lastname, following.id, following.user_id, following.follow_id
FROM user
JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
JOIN tweets ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
JOIN following ON user.id = following.user_id and following.follow_id = 1
```

This query will give all tweets from user 1. And all tweets from users that follow user 1 i belive.

Comment: :) I just tried the exact same, but it gave me only the result from user 1. nothing from the user that follow user 1 :(

Comment: Omg, i was totally explaining it wrong. 
Im supposed to get the values from user.id = 1 and values of the user user.1 is following.
Im sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If this were my problem, I would start my troubleshooting with this query:

```
select count(*)
from user
where user.id = 1
```

If that returned a number greater than 0, I would then run this:

```
select count(*)
from user u inner join userdetails ud on u.id = ud.id
where u.id = 1
```

Then I would continue to add the other bits one at a time until the query returned 0.  When it did, I'd know why.

Comment: The thing is that I have the query for both returning the values of user.id = 1 and following.follow_id .

Its when im trying to combine them i get zero result.