# Get results from two tables from id and following id

Tags: mysql, sql

Since I am quite  pixilated sometimes I asked wrong question before.
Now this is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Im trying to get the values from `user.id = 1` and the values of the user that `user.id = 1` is following.

But I ether get the results from `user.id 1` or in this case the followed `following.follow_id = 2`.
Any ideas ?

I have created a SQLfiddle for showing. As you see the only result I get is from user_one.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a39f/1

```
SELECT user.email, 
user.username, 
tweets.message, 
tweets.date, 
userdetails.profile_img, 
userdetails.firstname, 
userdetails.lastname, 
following.id, following.user_id, 
following.follow_id
FROM user
JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
JOIN tweets ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
LEFT JOIN following ON user.id = 1
WHERE following.user_id = 1
```

Tables:

**Tweets**

> user_id | id | date | message

**user**

> id | email | password | username

**userdetails**

> id | firstname | lastname | profile_img | user_id | about

**following**

> id | user_id | follow_id

In this case following table has value

```
 user_id = 1 and follow_id = 2
```

summary .

```
User_id = 1 is following follow_id = 2
```

But i only get results from `user_id = 1` and not from both.
Thanks.

Basicly Im trying to combine this two querys.

Query for getting the results from the user thats been followed.

```
SELECT user.email, 
user.username, 
tweets.message, 
tweets.date, 
userdetails.profile_img, 
userdetails.firstname, 
userdetails.lastname, 
following.id, following.user_id, 
following.follow_id
FROM user
JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
JOIN tweets ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
JOIN following ON following.follow_id
WHERE following.follow_id = tweets.user_id AND following.user_id  = '1' ORDER BY tweets.date DESC
```

And the query for fetching the value of user 1

```
SELECT user.email, 
user.username, 
tweets.message, 
tweets.date, 
userdetails.profile_img, 
userdetails.firstname, 
userdetails.lastname
FROM user
JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
JOIN tweets ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
WHERE user.id = '1'  ORDER BY tweets.date DESC
```

Comment: I'm confused - can you have a go at rewriting the question?

Comment: @m.edmondson .
Im trying to get the values from user.id = 1 and values from the user that user.id 1 is following.

Comment: how about showing some sample data?

Comment: @PraveenNambiar I added some more code, to the question.

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL flavor) are you using? Though you have a generic query this information might become useful if we need to test some solution.

Comment: @PM77-1 Im using MySQL with PDO

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch values from different tables with same ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132417/fetch-values-from-different-tables-with-same-id)

Comment: Please clarify the following (no pun intended): do you want to include users that **follow** this user or are **being followed** by this user?

Comment: If you **really** want this issue resolved, please spent some time to create minimally required sample data and (very important) your expected result based ob this data.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes Sorry about all the data i have in the question, But sometimes its easier. even if i understand that it could be to long to read :). well I want to include users that user one in following.
in table following the data is user_id = 1 and follow_id = 2.
the data from follow_id 2 included with the data of user_id 1

Comment: So you want the full data (all the specified fields) for the one user you selected and all the users this one user follows (including their followers and all)?  If this is the case then look at `bobs`'s answer.   He seems to get it right.

Comment: @PM77-1 yes that exactly, I am having some issues with bobs answer at the moment.

Comment: I posted my version *shamelessly* based on `bobs`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my (slightly) modified version of `bobs`'s answer (added `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and modified the sub-query):

```
SELECT user.id,
  user.email, 
  user.username, 
  tweets.message, 
  tweets.date, 
  userdetails.profile_img, 
  userdetails.firstname, 
  userdetails.lastname, 
  following.id, following.user_id, 
  following.follow_id
FROM user
LEFT JOIN following ON user.id = following.user_id 
JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
JOIN tweets ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
WHERE user.id=1 OR 
                user.id IN (SELECT follow_id 
                            FROM following 
                            WHERE following.user_id = 1);
```

Here's my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7ed2/10) with 3rd user added. Please see if it works for your real data set.

Comment: Hey, Hope you know I really appreciate all the help.
unfortunately its only giving me the result from user,id=1 and nothing about the user that we are following :( 
Ill could export my sql and create an paste bin if you like ?

Comment: well here is a pastebin of my database.
relative simple one. But I have been stuck with this problem since yesterday...

http://pastebin.com/hhutDUTK

Comment: I found this tool. its like jsfiddle but for SQL.

this is the result i get with your code.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a39f/1

Comment: Yes, I know. I already built my `fiddle` from your `pastebin`.

Comment: I see working like a charm on the fiddle, but in my data it gives me Error
SQL query:
WHERE user.id =1 OR user_id = following.follow_id;

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user.id = 1 OR user_id = following.follow_id' at line 1

Comment: Strange. You didn't forget about my `LEFT JOIN`, did you? I just put it a couple of lines higher.

Comment: No, I just copy and paste it. don't know why it isn't working in php admin

Comment: Well... It was my typo. Should've been `user.id`. Already fixed the answer here. Updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e83e/3

Comment: Hmm i actually saw the typo and changed that. but I still gets the error...this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Ill try to recreate my db with the same values as the fiddle. maybe some reverse building helps me find the trouble.

Comment: I see now that the sqlfiddle actually gives back right results. but with an error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28622/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-dymond)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to get data where the ID is 1 or the ID is one or more other values.  So, you might start with this

```
SELECT user.email, 
  user.username, 
  tweets.message, 
  tweets.date, 
  userdetails.profile_img, 
  userdetails.firstname, 
  userdetails.lastname, 
  following.id, following.user_id, 
  following.follow_id
FROM user
JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
JOIN tweets ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
WHERE user.id = 1
  OR user_id IN
      (
       SELECT follow_id
       FROM following
       WHERE user.id = following.user_id
       )
```

Comment: sorry for late answer been afk. Ill get the error message 
Unknown column 'following.id' in 'field list'
And if I JOIN following table it gives me 
 Column 'user_id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you rewrite the last two lines as

```
LEFT JOIN following ON following.user_id = user.id
WHERE user.id = 1
```

I don't think the ON clause of your following table's left join will work as it is now.

Comment: It gave me the same results. only results from user 1. nothing from the user we are following. =/